# How to hide prev/next controls in "Galleriffic" plugin for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, slideshow

In our project we use plugin for jQuery - **Galleriffic** (http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/), it allows you to do slideshow with photo set.

How to hide buttons prev/next in "**pagination**" block?

In the navigation ("**pagination**" block) should be only the page numbers without buttons prev/next.

Comment: dude  U got everything from plugin. nd now you asking question like this..!! why dont u post your project idea here. I will do it and send it to u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

In jquery.gallerific.js is a function which is responsible for creating the block "**pagination**" (it is called "**buildPager**"), in it creates the buttons prev/next.

We must find in "**buildPager**" line "/ / Prev Page Link" and put to the button "prev" class "hide" (in the css should be spelled out the relevant rule - .hide{display: none;}).

A similar procedure should be done and for the button "next".